# How do I evaluate this integral using a strange bound?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I need to evaluate this:

$$\frac{2}{(mw\pi \hbar)^{1/2}} \int_{\sqrt{mw\hbar}}^\infty \exp\left(-\frac{p^2}{mw\hbar}\right)dp$$

I'm new to *Mathematica*, so I'm not quite sure how to debug this. Here is my attempt at integrating this:

```
(2/((m*w*π*ℏ)^(1/2)))*Integrate[E^(-p^2/(ℏ*m*w)), p, Sqrt[m*w*ℏ], Infinity]
```

I get this error:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I goofed. The problem was that I didn't realize that Mathematica requires curly brackets around the integration variable and the bounds of integration.

Solution:

```
(2/((m*w*π*ℏ)^(1/2)))*Integrate[E^(-p^2/(ℏ*m*w)), {p, Sqrt[m*w*ℏ], Infinity}]
```